# How to compute integral of $\frac{1}{5 - 4\sin(x) + 3\cos(x)}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

So, I need to compute a integral for
$$
\frac{1}{5-4 \sin(x) + 3 \cos(x)}.
$$
On integral calculator the following transformation is made:
$$
-\frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2\right)^2}.
$$

I have no idea how the first expression is transformed into the second one. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Use [Tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)
$$\sin x=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}~~~,~~~\cos x=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}~~~,~~~dx=\dfrac{2}{1+t^2}$$
and then $t-2=u$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\sin x
= \frac{2\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\cos x
= \frac{1- \tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
$$
We have
\begin{align*}
5 - 4\sin x + 3\cos x
& = 5 - 4 \frac{2\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} + 3\frac{1- \tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \\
& = \frac{5+5\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - 8\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + 3 - 3\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \\
& =\frac{2\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - 4\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + 4\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \\
& = \frac{2\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2\right)^2}{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
\end{align*}
So,
$$
\frac{1}{5 - 4\sin x + 3\cos x}
= \frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2\right)^2}.
$$
Then the numerator is the derivative of $ \tan(x/2)-2$. [ $d\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$ ].

So,
$$I = \int\frac{{d\left( \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2\right)}}{\left( \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2\right)^2} = -\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2} +c$$

Comment: @ViktorSmith Ok, then my question is, if I have a problem like this, how do I know which way should I transform the expression to compute a integration?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$5+3\cos x-4\sin x=5(1+\cos(x+\arccos\dfrac35))$$

$$\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$$

Answer (score 0):

**A variant hint**:

Write $3\cos x-4\sin x$ as $\;5\cos(x+\varphi)$, where 
\begin{cases}\cos\varphi= \frac35,\\
\sin\varphi= \frac45.
\end{cases}
Then use the substitution $u=x+\varphi$ to obtain
\begin{align}\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{5 - 4\sin(x) + 3\cos(x)}&=\int\frac{\mathrm d u}{5(1+\cos u)}=\int\frac{1-\cos u}{5\sin^2 u}\,\mathrm d u=\int\frac{\mathrm d u}{5(1+\cos u)}\\[1ex]&=\int\frac{1-\cos u}{5\sin^2 u}\,\mathrm d u=\frac15\int\frac{\mathrm d u}{\sin^2 u}-\frac15\int\frac{\cos u}{\sin^2 u}\,\mathrm d u.
\end{align}